# On Key Press, Whilst UserForm In Background

Tags: excel, vba

I know we can detect if a key is pressed e.g. `KeyAscii = 8`, however I have only seen this done on events whilst the userform app is the window in operation.

Is it possible to have the window in the background e.g. whilst I am using IE, I can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> and my app recognizes it and does an action?

Comment: I'm not sure that this can be done easily.  Imagine if you had several worksheets in the background, all of which were waiting for the same key combination?  How would Windows know for which one the key combination was intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*At least to my own knowledge the answer is - **it's not possible, but..***

---

### 1. Things we need to know

Let's get some facts straight before we do any coding:

- The [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) application will not be able to execute any code while the `Window` object is in `xlMinimzed` state
- So basically as soon as the user will **close, minimize or even tab out** of the Application, we **no longer will be able to detect** any `OnKey` *(or any other)* events, as the currently active application (ie. browser) takes precedence over the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) Application

  - hence <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> will now zoom out of the page as it's the browser's default behaviour.
- With that being said, we can do at least some things to get close to at least some form of usefulness out of this.

---

### 2. The Application Layout

Since you have not provided specific application details, I created this mockup:

[image]

- A `Worksheet` consisting of a single `CommandButton`, that launches the `UserForm1`
  [image]

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     UserForm1.Show
  End Sub
  ```
- A Module named `Module1` which contains a simple hello world message (for the `OnKey` event)

  ```
  Public Sub hello()
     MsgBox "Hello world!"
  End Sub
  ```
- And the `UserForm1` which contains the code for our `OnKey` handling

  ```
  Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

     With ActiveWindow
         .WindowState = xlNormal
         ' we need to change window state to xlNormal
         ' xlMaximized would result in width/height property changing error
         ' and with xlMinimized our Onkey would not work
         .Width = 0
         .Height = 0
     End With

     Range("A1").Select
     ' we need a range selected, otherwise Application OnKey will not fire
     Application.OnKey "^0", "Module1.hello" ' launches hello world procedure
     Me.Hide

  End Sub
  ```

Now that's enough to have the window (almost) minimized and respond to a keypress

[image]

---

### 3. If we want to show the `UserForm` while maintaing functionality

Now let's say we want the `UserForm` while hiding the rest of the [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) Application in the background.

In order to do this, we need to:

1. Change the `UserForm` to `vbModeless`

   To do this, select the `UserForm` object and show properties (<kbd>F4</kbd>)
   [image]
2. Remove the `Me.Hide` line from our `UserForm1` code

   ```
   Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

      With ActiveWindow
         .WindowState = xlNormal
         .Width = 0
         .Height = 0
      End With

      Range("A1").Select
      Application.OnKey "^0", "Module1.hello"

      ' Me.Hide <- remove me

   End Sub
   ```

That leaves us with the following fucntionality

[image]

---

> *If there are any suggestions for improvement / optimization I'd be
>   happy to know as this question intrigued me quite a bit.
>   I'll try to keep the answer updated!*

Comment: Hi, really clever solution, thanks - I can amend accordingly and give it a whirl. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps one more referral I can somewhat recommend. You can also disable the minimization buttons to enforce user to have the application window, albeit tabbing out will still essentially minimize it regardless https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/106206-disable-minimize-restore-close-buttons

Comment: I dabbled adding this to my answer, but thought it was complex enough already